# Build view with new child views in regions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I use Marionette 3.0.

I have BlockView which could have variable number of regions.
These regions are filled with BlockRegionViews which are CollectionViews (they would be in 2.x) and these views render further BlockViews.
I would like to write a function that create a BlockView with it's regions already filled with (empty) BlockRegionViews, and than return this BlockView.

So i've written this code:

```
var blockView = new BlockView({model: blockModel});
var regions = blockModel.get('regions')
for(var i in regions) {
    var blockRegionModel = regions[i];
    var blockRegionView = new BlockRegionView({model: blockRegionModel});
    blockView.addRegion(blockRegionModel.get('position'), '...regiondefinition...');
    var region = blockView.getRegion(blockRegionModel.get('position'));
    // This is the line where i get the error.
    region.show(blockRegionView);
}
return blockView;
```

Of course my code is bad. Even the show function's name suggests that it's not the right function for me (since i don't want to show any views at this time), but I can't find anything like this in the documentation.

So my question is: How should i build a View with other views initialized in it's regions without rendering any of them?

Comment: CollectionViews are still a part of the 3.x version of Marionette, however LayoutView and ItemView are now just called View (they were very similar anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to render views within a view, and not render anything until it all has been initialized.

Your blockModel and region handling in your description was a bit confusing, so I hope you can apply this to your case.

The documentation around [a View's lifecycle](http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/viewlifecycle.html#view-lifecycle) is helpful.

```
var ChildView = Mn.View.extend({..});

var ParentView = Mn.View.extend({
  template: //..,
  onBeforeRender: function() {
    this.showChildView('reg1', new ChildView({model: someModel}));
  },
  regions: {
    reg1: //..
  }
});
```

In the above example the `ChildView` will be instantiated and attached to the `ParentView` before the `ParentView` has been rendered. However when the `ParentView` is rendered, the `ChildViews` will be instantiated and rendered in it's region.

You mentioned you don't want to render anything. That's a rare case, but you could instantiate child views outside of any rendering events.

```
var ChildView = Mn.View.extend({..});

var ParentView = Mn.View.extend({
  template: //..,
  initialize: function() {
    this.childView = new ChildView({model: someModel});
  },

  // You can decide whenever you want to show the childView
  // and invoke this method.
  showTheChildView: function() {
    this.getRegion('reg1').show(this.childView);
  },

  regions: {
    reg1: //..
  }
});
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.